# Sqoop Query into Hive Table

Tags: hive, sqoop

I want to specify a file location in the `--query` argument of a sqoop import query, something like this
`--query "/home_dir/z0027vp/sqoop_common.sql"`

Is it possible in Hive?  I searched online regarding this and could not find information regarding it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible in sqoop import. You have to mention SQL query itself in `--query` argument.

First of all you can't use your SQL as it it in sqoop free form query. You need to add  `WHERE $CONDITIONS` in the query.

Check [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports) for more details.

So read this file `home_dir/z0027vp/sqoop_common.sql` and modifty SQL by adding `WHERE $CONDITIONS` and then modify your shell script and execute sqoop command.

Comment: Can you please suggest any method to do this, I want to read the query from a .sql file

Comment: How are you executing sqoop query? Shell script or Java code or something else ?

Comment: Shell Script...  Here's the Sqoop command I'm using:                          
sqoop import  \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ed05db01:10501/WFMP01 \
--username  \
--password  \
--split-by TSCHD_SKEY \
--num-mappers 100 \
--query "/home_dir/z0027vp/sqoop_common.sql  \
--hive-import \
--hive-table hre_sec_work.WFM_FCT_TSCHD_E_prac_dmp \
--target-dir /user/Z0027VP/WFM \
--delete-target-dir \

Comment: dev, thanks for the updated answer, my requirement was met after using your suggestion.

Comment: @VarunKR Happy to hear that !